# Insert clip - but only the part with a given marker?

Tags: premiere

I'm trying to make a video in Adobe Premiere 2020, and one of the clips I intend to use is a good two and a half hours long.  Thus, I put a bunch of chapter markers in to mark which parts of the clip would be useful for different parts of the eventual video.  Is there any good way to insert just the part of the clip that a given marker covers (for example, a marker covering from 0:00:43:00 to 0:02:27:00 for near the beginning of the video) or do I just have to type the timecodes in manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subclips:

1. jump to first marker
2. set in point
3. jump to next marker
4. set out point
5. in the menu "Clip" -> "Make Subclip" (or use shortcut)
6. give it a useful name

Repeat.

Comment: So I should have used subclips instead of markers?

Comment: Yes, the markers are superfluous for this task.